# multiprocess the rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe df1 with N rows. Each row, through complicated calculations, will result in up to K rows. So the source dataframe df1 with N rows will result in an output dataframe dfY with NxK rows. The real df1 can have N=1,000 rows, with calculations that can take 1s per row and can generate several thousand output rows K for each processed row N. Multiprocessing would be useful.

For simplicity, let's assume that the algorithm that calculates the K rows is just a silly way to prepare a cross product, but without using merge. My problem is that the following example works without multiprocessing, within 12ms: function unip().

But with multiprocessing, the code gets stuck in some endless loop: function multip(). What do I do wrong when I try to apply row-wise multiprocessing to df1 in multip()?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp  

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.meshgrid(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])).T.reshape(-1,2), columns=['Product', 'Store'])
df1.iloc[[0,-1]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,13), columns=['Month'])
df2.iloc[[0,-1]]

def row_to_df(row):
    dfX = df2.copy()
    dfX.loc[:, "Product"] = row[0]  #row["Product"]
    dfX.loc[:, "Store"] = row[1]    #row["Store"]
    return dfX

def unip():
    for i, row in enumerate(df1.itertuples(index=False)):
        dfX = row_to_df(row)
        if i == 0:
            dfY = dfX.copy()
        else:
            dfY = pd.concat([dfY, dfX], axis=0)
    return dfY




def iterate_rows(df):
    for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(index=False)):
        dfX = row_to_df(row)
        if i == 0:
            dfY = dfX.copy()
        else:
            dfY = pd.concat([dfY, dfX], axis=0)
    dfY = dfY.reset_index(drop=True)
    display(dfY)
    return dfY


def multip():
    Nrows = df1.shape[0]
    Ncores = mp.cpu_count()
    Nparts = min([Nrows, Ncores])
    listParts = np.array_split(df1, Nparts)
    pool = mp.Pool(Ncores)
    dfY = pd.concat(pool.map(row_to_df, [iterate_rows(df) for df in listParts]))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return dfY

%%time
dfY = unip()
dfY

%%time
dfY = multip()
dfY
```

The display(dfY) in iterate_rows() shows that multip creates the dataframe chunks for the Product/Store rows from (A,X) to (C,Z)  as intended. But multip never completes their concatenation as unip() does.

Comment: Use `with mp.Pool(...)` so you don't need to `close` or `join` by hand.

Comment: Also, there's a bug in that the `multip` implementation is not passing tuples to `row_to_df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `multip()` implementation should just be

```
def multip():
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        dfY = pd.concat(
            pool.imap(
                row_to_df,
                df1.itertuples(index=False, name=None),
                chunksize=20,
            )
        )
    return dfY
```

for it to work equivalently to `unip()`.

That said, for this test data and algorithm it's about 90x slower than `unip()` – you'll want to check whether that holds true for your actual algorithm and data.

You may also wish to check out [`dask.dataframe`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html).

Comment: Thank you. But this multip() that uses pool.imap is now running for 8min with no end in sight, and no erroor message, where unip() needed 12ms. Is something wrong with my multiprocessing package?

Comment: Are you running this as a regular Python script (which OS, Python version, etc.) or maybe from a notebook or something? With notebooks, I'd be willing to say all bets are off...

Comment: Originally in a notebook. Now, in a py file, it works, though 12 times slower than unip.

Comment: Yep. It's likely spending a lot of time serializing and deserializing data to go "over the wire" to subprocesses.

Comment: I found the solution for notebooks. The original multiprocessing is incompatible with notebooks because it uses pickling, but its fork multiprocess is because it uses dill. https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess